# Bootstrap put image to left of columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code: http://www.bootply.com/ZZw7dYczJD

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
```

At the moment my image appears on the top of my row content but I want it to appear to the left. Can anyone tell me how I might implement it please, do I need another column for the image?

Comment: just wrap it in another `col-xs` on which would always be where you want it to bee. sth. like http://www.bootply.com/3w1aVQj0yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image in its own `col-md-2` or if it's smaller then its own `col-md-1`.  For centering purposes you may want to add a `col-md-offset-1` to the image.

You will have to adjust the width of the other columns so that you do not exceed 12 units across among all of the columns.

#### [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/DSFHt7LuOe)

Comment: When I make a full example it flows onto the next line, what is it I have done wrong? EDIT: http://www.bootply.com/Hdsvazjubq

Comment: You can only use 12 columns across, which includes your offsets.  I suggested using offset assuming that you only had one image to the left.  However if you're going to add images to all 4 columns then remove the offset, like this: http://www.bootply.com/6U3kvpOyJt